# How to reduce file size of model that has shape keys?

Tags: rigging, shape-keys

I have a blender model. I am using the 52 ARKit shape keys. Without the shapekeys, my exported .DAE file is about 8 MB. When I export with shape keys, it balloons up to 480 MBs. I need the shape keys because I am using them to animate the face in my ARKit iOS app.

Is there a way to export my file in a way that doesn't have a huge file size?